# Go alternative to JDBC batch inserts on Oracle

Tags: oracle, go

I have this dead-simple script that reads a single column text file and writes them to a table in Oracle along with a constant value.

The problem I'm having is that for our largest files (~3k lines) the whole process is taking a little over 1 minute to run, which seems absurd.

These same files can be processed using JDBC's batch operations in milliseconds.

So I guess my questions are:

- What am I doing wrong here?
- What is the Go option that can be used to mimic whatever the Java Oracle driver is doing for JDBC batch operations?

The Go script I have:

```golang
func execute(udid, schema string, file *os.File, db *sql.DB) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    query := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO %s.UD_GeneId VALUES (:1, :2)", schema)

    tx := mustReturn(db.Begin())
    defer tx.Rollback()

    stmt := mustReturn(tx.Prepare(query))

    for scanner.Scan() {
        _ = mustReturn(stmt.Exec(udid, scanner.Text()))
    }

    must(tx.Commit())
}
```

My Kotlin implementation I'd like to get comparable performance to:

```kotlin
fun execute(datasetId: String, schema: String, file: File, db: DataSource) {
  db.connection.use { conn ->
    conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ${schema}.UD_GeneId VALUES (?, ?)").use { ps ->
      file.bufferedReader().useLines { lines ->
        lines.filter { it.isNotBlank() }
          .forEach { geneId ->
            ps.setString(1, datasetId)
            ps.setString(2, geneId)
            ps.addBatch()
          }
      }

      ps.executeBatch()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see a `database/sql` ticket for adding batch support on golang's github which makes me wonder if this is just left up to the individual driver implementations to handle: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5171

Comment: Batch is supported in [`godror`](https://github.com/godror/godror), see [`Batch.Add`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/godror/godror#Batch.Add). And this driver allows vertical/vectorized batch binding according to the User Guide, [Godror Tuning paragraph](https://godror.github.io/godror/doc/tuning.html): see DML section.

Comment: I'm using go_ora, but the realization that the driver implementations themselves support batch operations resolves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @astentx in the comment thread on my initial post, it was brought to my attention that the Oracle driver implementations themselves may support batch operations.  `go_ora` and `godror` both support batch operations by passing slices of values to the prepared statement execute method.

Reference:

- https://github.com/godror/godror/issues/259
- https://github.com/sijms/go-ora#arrays